# Передача строки в функцию

Tags: c

Как можно передать строку в функцию так, чтобы манипуляции с этой строкой внутри функции не меняли ее значения при выходе из функции?

Comment: Создать внутри функции новую строку, в которую скопировать исходную.

Comment: Сделать копию строки придётся в любом случае, в самой функции или перед передачей в неё - решать вам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языке С нет типа "строка". Я не знаю, что имели в виду Вы, но при работе со строками, в качестве параметра функции передаётся **указатель** тип *char **. В соответствии с общей идеологией языка С этот указатель **не** меняется. Но Вы легко можете, находясь внутри функции, изменить (испортить?) ту память, на которую указывает этот указатель.

Если Вы не собираесь менять содержимое памяти, переданной в функцию по указателю, то проще всего гарантировать себя от проблем так:

```
void function(char *str) {

    char *cp;

    cp = malloc(strlen(str)+1);   // Выделяем память под копию строки
    strcpy(cp, str);              // Копируем содержимое строки
    // Здесь что-то делаем с полученной строкой
    free(cp);                     // Освобождаем занятую память
    return;
}
```

Comment: Именно то, что было нужно, спасибо большое <3

Comment: а можно вместо malloc+strcpy использовать strdup, хотя она как то полустандартная.