# Не могу передать массив char в функцию

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

```
//в методе getCryptInfo строчка strcaps(msg) вылетает с ошибкой. как передать аргумент getCryptInfo в strcaps
//пишу под vs2019 без компилятора gcc

#include<stdio.h>

void getCryptInfo(char msg[], char key[]);
char* strcaps(char* s);

int main(void) {
    getCryptInfo("zzTzHECRAZYPROGRAMMER1", "HELLO");//zzTzHECRAZYPROGRAMMER1 to uppercase
    getCryptInfo("ATTACKATDAWN", "LEMON");
    getCryptInfo("1", "BAG");

    return 0;
}

char* strcaps(char* s)
{
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        *s = toupper(*s);
        s++;
    }
    return s;
}

void getCryptInfo(char msg[], char key[]) {
    //char a[] = *msg; doesnt work or void getCryptInfo(*msg ...)
    char a[] = "zz";//works
    strcaps(a);
    //strcaps(msg); doesnt work
    printf("%s", a);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Строковые литералы модифицировать нельзя. Связанный вопрос: [C. Таблица строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1245053).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Передача строки в функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1209865).

Comment: спасибо, закрываю вопрос.

Comment: думаю, что есть решение через *char;

Comment: Есть, конечно. Инициализируете _массивы_ строковыми литералами `char a1[] = "zzTzHECRAZYPROGRAMMER1"; char a2[] = "HELLO";`. И уже указатели на первые элементы этих массивов передавайте в функцию `getCryptInfo`: `getCryptInfo(a1, a2);`. По ссылкам, что я вам привёл ранее, такой подход рассматривался. Либо внутри `getCryptInfo` создавайте копию строки и работайте с ней. Либо считывайте символ из строки, изменяйте регистр и сразу выводите, не сохраняя его в исходную строку.

Comment: еще раз спасибо за ответ, по заданию нужно три раза ввести разные данные. Получается a1 a2 еще два раза переписывают значение. многовато строк, поэтому не рассматривал такой вариант.